# Pseudo-random number generation algorithms

Tags: algorithms, random-variable, random-generation

What algorithms are used in modern and good-quality random number generators?

Comment: Retagged "random-variate" to "random-variable" for consistency with similar questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In R, the default setting for random number generation are:

1. For U(0,1), use the Mersenne-Twister algorithm
2. For Guassian numbers use  the numerical inversion of the standard normal distribution function.

You can easily check this, viz.

```
> RNGkind()
[1] "Mersenne-Twister" "Inversion"
```

It is possible to change the default generator to other PRNGs, such as Super-Duper,Wichmann-Hill, Marsaglia-Multicarry or even a user-supplied PRNG. See the ?RNGkind for further details. I have never needed to change the default PRNG.

The [C GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-number-environment-variables.html) library also uses the [Mersenne-Twister](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-number-generator-algorithms.html) by default.

Comment: Are you sure about your second point, generating normal random variables by inverting the CDF?  The inverse of the normal CDF is a fairly expensive function to evaluate.  I imagine Box-Muller's method would be faster.  Faster still would be Marsaglia's ziggurat method for generating normals.

Comment: I also find this suspicious. Marsaglia's Ziggurat is the default in Matlab, and I can't imagine Matlab being better than R in the field of random number generation.

Comment: @John Indeed, the polar method is available in R, see the setRNG package.

Answer (score 7):

The [Mersenne Twister](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister) is one I've come across and used before now.

Comment: e.g., Python (http://j.mp/9TVyhv), Perl (http://j.mp/by85El), Octave (http://j.mp/aVQ5Xz), Clojure (http://j.mp/dkj9Z9, not the default one), Haskell (http://j.mp/aWK7kK), lua (http://j.mp/bSD2vO), or even SQL (http://j.mp/aOPJMW, for an overview) :-)

Answer (score 4):

The Xorshift PNG designed by George Marsaglia. Its period (2^128-1) is much shorter than the Mersenne-Twister but the algorithm is very simple to implement and lends itself to parallelization. Performs well on many-core architectures such as DSP chips and Nvidia's Tesla.

Comment: Would this be good for implementing on GPUs?  Link to details, references?

Comment: Thomas, Howes, Luk - 2009 - A comparison of CPUs, GPUs, FPGAs, and massively parallel processor arrays for random number generation. http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/1508128.1508139.

Discussion + benchmarks of a set of PNGs executing on CPU, GPU, FPGA and Massively Parallel Processor Arrays.

Comment: Maybe also L'Ecuyer's RNG with multiple streams (http://j.mp/bzJSlm)?

Answer (score 3):

At http://prng.di.unimi.it/ you can find a shootout of several random number generators tested using TestU01, the modern test suite for pseudorandom number generators that replaced diehard and dieharder. You can pick and choose.